# Display html form values inside hyperlink in same page after submit using javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

This is a working script i found online

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML JavaScript output on same page</title>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
        function showMessage(){
            var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
            display_message.innerHTML= message;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
Enter message: <input type="text" id = "message">
<input type="button" onclick="showMessage()" value="submit" />
</form>
<p> Message is: <span id = "display_message"></span> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

how can I show the output inside a hyperlink? i tried this but getting an error

`<a href="https://google.com/<span id="display_message"></span>">Test</a>`

Comment: What you mean by inside hyperlink? Did you mean to append the values?

Comment: You cannot insert an HTML element inside the attribute value of another element. You need to 1. grab the <a> using document.getElementById()/querySelector() 2. read its href attribute using either .href or .getAttribute('href') 3. append the textfield value to the URL string 4. store that back into the href attribute by directly setting it or using .setAttribute()

Comment: However if this is an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/) and what you actually want is to enter text, then click a button to google it: https://jsfiddle.net/qw6s1jvr/ (note the form's `action` and the input's `name`, which will compose the URL you need)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the question, but here is how to put it in a link and show that it is in the link.

```
<body>
  <body>
  <form>
  Enter message: <input type="text" id = "message">
  <input type="button" onclick="showMessage()" value="submit" />
  </form>
  <p> Message is: <a id="display_message" href="https://google.com/"></span></a> </p>

  <script>
    function showMessage(){
      const href = 'https://google.com/';
      var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
      display_message.innerHTML = href + message;
      display_message.href = href + message
    }
  </script>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```